# How to find out row count returned in postgres function?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

In the following SQL, I need to check if more than one record is returned from the select clause.

The **_person.length** is not working, meanwhile, I can't select count(*) into another variable.
How do I know how many rows returned in the select then?

```
create or replace function search_users(partial_name text)
returns setof text
as $$
declare
    _person record;
begin
    select  * into _person 
      from users
     where name ~ partial_name;

    if not found then
        return next 'No matching user';
    elsif _person.length > 1 then
        return next 'Ambiguous user name';
    else
        return next _person.name;
    end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns more than one row, you will get an error because of the `INTO _person` clause which can't get a set of records. You can instead aggregate the resulting rows into an array and then check the length of the array :

```
create or replace function search_users(partial_name text)
returns text
as $$
declare
    _person text[] ;
begin
    select string_agg(name) into _person 
      from users
     where name ~ partial_name;

    if not found then
        return next 'No matching user';
    elsif array_length(_person, 1) > 1 then
        return next 'Ambiguous user name';
    else
        return next _person[1] ;
    end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```